# My C drive displays as a folder

Tags: hard-drive, local

My local C disk drive is showing as a folder and shows it as being empty.  My computer runs but I can not access the c drive. How do I change the folder back to a local drive?

Comment: It seemed that the system is attached by the virus so scan the system with anti-virus.Check whether the restart fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

Try restarting your computer into Safe Mode. 
Once there, restart back into Normal Mode. 
This should rebuild your `ShellIconCache` file and should correct the problem.